# RESTLET-HELLO WORLD in GWT

Tags: gwt, restlet-2.0

I worked out a simple hello world application using Restlet in GWT, but it throwed out me with

> "No available client connector supports the required protocol: 'HTTP'"
>   in client side and in server side
>
> "No available server connector supports the required protocols: 'HTTP'
>   . Please add the JAR of a matching connector to your classpath."

Here is my hello world app:

Client:

```
import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

public class HelloClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClientResource helloClientresource = new ClientResource(
                "http://localhost:8111/");
        helloClientresource.get().write(System.out);
    }
}
```

ServerResource:

```
import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

/**
 * Simple "hello, world" server resource.
 */
public class HelloServerResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get("txt")
    public String represent() {
        return "hello, world";
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
public class HelloServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server helloServer = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8111,
                HelloServerResource.class);
        helloServer.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "No available server connector supports the required protocols: 'HTTP'
>   . Please add the JAR of a matching connector to your classpath"

Make sure you have added relevant jar file into your classpath:
For example:The GWT client relies only on the core Restlet JAR (org.restlet.jar) provided in the GWT edition. And also see FAQ: [What JAR files must I have in my classpath for a minimal application?](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.0/faq#04) and also see the answer given here: [No available client connector supports the required protocol: 'HTTP'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684452/no-available-client-connector-supports-the-required-protocol-http)

Comment: yup,i have added necessary jar files ,and i am using restlet 2.0,which comes with built-in HTTP client and servers !